# Laravel upload image through modal using ajax/jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, upload

I'm making a small system that has inventory in it. I have a products table that has an `image` column that represents a picture of a specific product. My problem is why I can't upload using my modal and ajax code in my project in Laravel? Does anyone know how to solve this issue? I spend 2 days already in figuring out how to solve this error:

> message: "Undefined index: product_name"

I already made the fields fillable in my model. Help will be highly appreciated.

[image: output]

Modal Code

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Register New Product</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <p style="font-weight: bold;">Name </p>
          <input   type="text" class="form-control" id="product_name"/>
          <p style="font-weight: bold;">Description </p>
          <input   type="text" class="form-control" id="description"/>
          <p style="font-weight: bold;">Price </p>
          <input   type="text" class="form-control" id="currentprice"/>
          {{-- <input style="text-transform:uppercase"   type="text" class="form-control" id="supplier_id"/> --}}
          <p style="font-weight: bold;">Supplier </p>
          <select class="form-control"  id="supplier_id"  >
              @foreach ($suppliers as $supplier)
          <option value="{{$supplier->id}}">{{$supplier->name}}</option>
              @endforeach
              </select>
         <p style="font-weight: bold;">Picture </p>
          <input  type="file" class="form-control" id="picture"/>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add_product">Add</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Script

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    //add
    $('#add_product').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = $('#product_name').val();
        var description = $('#description').val();
        var price = $('#currentprice').val();
        var supplier_id = $('#supplier_id').val();
        var image = $('#picture').val();

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: "{{    url('/product')     }}",
            method: 'post',
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            processData: false, 
            contentType: false,
            data:{
                product_name: name,
                description: description,
                price: price,
                supplier_id: supplier_id,
                image: image,
            },
            success: function (res) {
                console.log(res);
                window.location.href = '{{route("products")}}'
            }
        });
    });
});
```

ProductsController.php

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        $data['product_name'] = ($data['product_name']);
        $data['description'] = ($data['description']);
        $data['supplier_id'] = ($data['supplier_id']);
        $data['price'] = ($data['price']);



        if ($request->hasFile('image')){
            //Add new photo
                $image = $request->file('image');
                $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $location = public_path('img/' . $filename);
                Image::make($image)->resize(300,300)->save($location);
                $oldFilename = $products->image;
            //Update DB
                $products->image = $filename;
             //Delete the old photo
                // Storage::delete($oldFilename);
            }

        Product::create($data);
        return response()->json($data);
    }
```

route for products

```
//products
Route::resource('product', 'ProductsController');
```

Comment: someone help me

Comment: what you see in `dd($data)` after `$data = $request->all();`?

Comment: You may also check the header of your posted data.

Comment: i cant `dd($data)` sir because the modal wont close and the data is not submitted. i really want an end to this T_T @RomanBobrik

Comment: what do you mean the header sir @Phil ?

Comment: just open inspector in browser and go to the network tab. then check what your ajax query send to server

Comment: `dd($request->all();` before `$data = $request->all();` it will show in your browser network tab.

Comment: In the picture you provided, you could see `Headers  Preview  Response  Cookies  Timing`. In Headers, you could check whether all the data are posted.

Comment: its says `Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error` sir @Phil

Comment: open subtab `headers`, scroll down, show us what goes to server. then show us stack trace, you can see it in `preview` subtab

Comment: The headers is here sir https://imgur.com/a/coJm9On and the stack trace here  https://imgur.com/a/51T4cfT

Comment: show please headers at the very end. scroll down that tab

Comment: heres the headers end sir @RomanBobrik https://imgur.com/a/KQl5lqn

Comment: someone help T_T

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you send to server an object, when server expect JSON. Try to add dataType:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ url('/product') }}",
    method: 'post',
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    contentType: false,
    dataType: 'json', // setting of data type
    data:{
        product_name: name,
        description: description,
        price: price,
        supplier_id: supplier_id,
        image: image,
    },
    success: function (res) {
        console.log(res);
        window.location.href = '{{route("products")}}'
    }
});
```

Comment: same error encountered sir `message: "Undefined index: product_name"`. whats wrong with my code huhuhu

Comment: try to remove `processData: false,`

Comment: same error sir. what to do now? theres nothing wrong in my controller sir? right?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old but I faced the same problem in the past days so I think an answer could be usefull to other developers.

You need only to use FormData instead of serialize your form. Note that FormData need an HTMLFormElement so you need to add [0] to your jQuery object. And you have NOT to add dataType directive.

This is my code:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: new FormData(form[0]),
        url: form.attr('action'),
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
        success: function (data) {
            $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
            // YOUR SUCCESS MANAGEMENT
        },
        error: function (e) {
            $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
            // YOUR ERROR MANAGEMENT
        }
    });
});
```